# Firebase with ProGuard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, proguard

I'm making an app with firebase, which works perfectly.
That is until I turn on ProGuard or even R8.

I basically tried every combination of ProGuard rules I found on the internet, I even tried

```
-keep class com.firebase.** {*;}
-keep class mypackage.** {*;}
```

I had the exact same project, just with a different code structure and it does work perfectly with just the following rules:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers class com.tritrio.anabi2y.model.** {*;}

-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

-dontwarn com.firebase.ui.auth.**
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
2018-09-08 21:00:03.471 9889-9963/com.tritrio.anabi2y E/io.grpc.a.J: Creating atomic field updaters failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field streamClosed in class Lio/grpc/a/J$c; (declaration of 'io.grpc.a.J$c' appears in /data/app/com.tritrio.anabi2y-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:380)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:58)
    at io.grpc.a.J.<clinit>(CensusTracingModule.java:77)
    at io.grpc.a.c.c(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:420)
    at io.grpc.a.c.a(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:395)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.e.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:102)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.w.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:1217)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.y.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.c$a.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
 Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field streamClosed in class Lio/grpc/a/J$c; (declaration of 'io.grpc.a.J$c' appears in /data/app/com.tritrio.anabi2y-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:71)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:358)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:58) 
    at io.grpc.a.J.<clinit>(CensusTracingModule.java:77) 
    at io.grpc.a.c.c(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:420) 
    at io.grpc.a.c.a(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:395) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.e.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:102) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.w.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:1217) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.y.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.c$a.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:190) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field streamClosed in class Lio/grpc/a/J$c; (declaration of 'io.grpc.a.J$c' appears in /data/app/com.tritrio.anabi2y-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl$1.run(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:361)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl$1.run(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:360)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater$AtomicIntegerFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:358) 
    at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.java:58) 
    at io.grpc.a.J.<clinit>(CensusTracingModule.java:77) 
    at io.grpc.a.c.c(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:420) 
    at io.grpc.a.c.a(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:395) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.e.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:102) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.w.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:1217) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.y.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.c$a.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:190) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 
2018-09-08 21:00:03.743 9889-9922/com.tritrio.anabi2y E/Fabric: Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/com.tritrio.anabi2y/settings
2018-09-08 21:00:03.745 9889-9930/com.tritrio.anabi2y E/Answers: Failed to retrieve settings
2018-09-08 21:00:03.766 9889-9889/com.tritrio.anabi2y E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tritrio.anabi2y, PID: 9889
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.c.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:324)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.f.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
 Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.protobuf.y$d com.google.protobuf.y$d.a(int)"
    at com.google.protobuf.t.a(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1319)
    at b.a.c.a.F$b.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:2145)
    at b.a.c.a.F$b$a.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:428)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.f.p.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:665)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.N.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:150)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.w.b(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:82)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.O.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:479)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.V.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.u.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:117)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.c.O.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:474)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.f.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:165)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.t.a(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:79)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.w.c(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:132)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.b.C.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.c$a.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.0.5:190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

Here is my Project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha08'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And Here is my Modules's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tritrio.anabi2y"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
//        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en", "ar"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0-alpha3"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0"
//    implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0"
    implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0"
//    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5"
    implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R8 was the culprit.

After disabling it everything worked as expected.

I've reported the issue to [google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114554345) and firebase.

Comment: life saver! I spent hours on this

Answer (score 0):

You should use rules in official [Quickstart Samples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android)

These are often the rules for firebase android libraries

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

Comment: I already posted the solution. I tried this, didn't work, thanks for the answer.